# Wrong bounds when portrait iPhone app launched on iPad with landscape orientation

Tags: ios, swift, ipad, autolayout, uikit

I am creating a view controller programmatically without a storyboard. The app only supports "Portrait Device Orientation (checked in project general setting)".

When the app is launched with portrait orientation, it has a correct bounds `(0.0, 0.0, 375.0, 667.0)`; However, when the app is launched on iPad with landscape orientation the bounds change to `(0.0, 0.0, 667.0, 375.0)` and skew the auto layout constraints set programmatically.

As you can see from the screenshot below, the title in the navigation bar is no centered anymore, as well as all the content inside the view.

```
func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo _: UISceneSession, options _: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {
    // Use this method to optionally configure and attach the UIWindow `window` to the provided UIWindowScene `scene`.
    // If using a storyboard, the `window` property will automatically be initialized and attached to the scene.
    // This delegate does not imply the connecting scene or session are new (see `application:configurationForConnectingSceneSession` instead).
    guard let windowScene = (scene as? UIWindowScene) else { return }

    print(">>>", windowScene.coordinateSpace.bounds)
        
    window = UIWindow(frame: windowScene.coordinateSpace.bounds)
    window?.windowScene = windowScene
    window?.rootViewController = MyViewController()
    window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
}
```

[image]

Comment: Try constraint layout

Comment: you mean setting `NSLayoutConstraint`? can you elaborate your comment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A workaround is to switch the bounds width and height if the window starts with a none portrait orientation.

```
func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo _: UISceneSession, options _: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {
    // Use this method to optionally configure and attach the UIWindow `window` to the provided UIWindowScene `scene`.
    // If using a storyboard, the `window` property will automatically be initialized and attached to the scene.
    // This delegate does not imply the connecting scene or session are new (see `application:configurationForConnectingSceneSession` instead).
    guard let windowScene = (scene as? UIWindowScene) else { return }

    var bounds = windowScene.coordinateSpace.bounds
    let isPortrait = windowScene.interfaceOrientation.isPortrait
        
    if !isPortrait {
        let width = bounds.height
        let height = bounds.width
            
        bounds = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: width, height: height)
    }

    window = UIWindow(frame: bounds)
    window?.windowScene = windowScene
    window?.rootViewController = MyViewController()
    window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
}
```